# Best Method for online update

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ftp

I was trying to work out the best method of synchronising an update of files via vb.net. I want to automatically update some files in a few folders from an FTP site to a local drive. This would ideally be the same folder structure, but on a specified local folder. I have looked at the FTP methods in .net and am able to transfer individual files successfully, but wondered if there was an elegant method to collecting the entire folder from the FTP and it's contents to be re-created locally. I have established the reading of an XML via linq from the ftp to establish an update single and decide whether the local machine is up-to-date or not, it's just the transfer of the folders that i'm stuck on as it's different to using a IO method.

Can any gurus confirm that this is the best way of approaching this task?

cheers CS

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks fine to me. You will have to transfer the files/folders individually if you are using the base class library.
There *may* be 3rd party libraries available which will do this on one shot.

Comment: Hi NimsDotnet, thanks for your reply. So in FTP.net , is a folder treated as an object to be downloaded?, i.e. you get the directory listing and can download each part, whether it is a folder or not. Or do you have to work out what is folder and file and use a create directory command to make the same structure on the local drive? thanks! CS

Comment: I believe Chilkat has a Library that has a one-shot method, but I'd rather figure it out myself.

Comment: You will have to handle them as two different cases, download the files from server & create folders using create directory command.

Comment: Did some googling and found this link: http://www.copyandwaste.com/2007/12/25/parsing-webrequestmethodsftplistdirectorydetails-and-listdirectory/ hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Hi NimsDotNet, thought that might be the case. Nice find, I have been googling this for the last few evenings but hadn't found that. Thanks for your help so far. CS